# Unwanted nested level in react state shape (when dealing with JSON)

Tags: json, redux, fetch, axios

I'm just start playing with React\Redux (but there is no R\R issue). I'm trying to map some entities getting it's from server api, but when i get they - they auto-wrapped in deeper array level and i can't get they out). This is a my code snippets. I think there is nothing unusual:

```
import { getGroupList } from './actions/groupActions';

class GroupContainer extends Component {
 constructor (props){
    super(props);
 };


componentWillMount = function(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/groups.json')
    .then( (response) => {
      return response.json()
  })
    .then((json) => {
      return json.groups;
  })
    .then((result) => {
      this.props.onGetGroupList(result); //call action
  })
 };

render() {
    return (
        <div className="groups">
        { 
          this.props.groups.map( (group, index) => 
          { 
            return <Link key={index} to={`/group/${index}`} >
            <div id={index}><p>{group.name}</p></div></Link> 
          })
        }
        </div>
    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return {
    groups: state.groups
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  =>{
  return {
    onGetGroupList: (items) => dispatch(getGroupList(items))
  }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GroupContainer);
```

//reducers/groups.js   ... i will skip combineReducers, action creators - there is nothing interesting

```
const initialState = [];

export default function groups(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GROUP_LIST_SUCCESS':
    console.log(action);
      return [
        ...state,
        action.payload
      ];

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My groups.json file is:

```
{
  "groups": [{
      "name": "FIRST GROUP" 
    },
    {
      "name": "SECOND GROUP" 
    } 
  ]
}
```

In ReduxDevTools i see additional nested level on **groups** entities - **"0"**:[image: the group entities with additional nesting level]

And that's why map function can't iterate group items. As you can see above i have another one set - 'unions' without additional nesting. Unions sets as initialState of my other component reducer:

```
const initialState = [
  unions = {
    name: 'Some name',
    interval: '1-8.',
    father: '0'
  },
  {
    name: 'Some other name',
    interval: '1-11',
    father: '0'
  } 
   .....
];

export default function unions(state = initialState, action) {.....}
```

And i have no issues with rendering unions component. So my general question - whats the matter with json parsing (or what else)? I was trying use axios instead native fetching - same result. I was trying to **JSON.parse('{
  "groups": [{
      "name": "FIRST GROUP" 
    },
    {
      "name": "SECOND GROUP" 
    } 
  ]
}')** instead fetching url, with no luck. I always gets one deeper nested level in the shape of data. Any help, please.

Add later... /action/groupActions.js
    /*
     * action creators
     */

```
export function getGroupList(items) {
  console.log('groups_action_creator:',items);
  return {
    type: 'GROUP_LIST_SUCCESS',
    payload: items
  }
};
```

Comment: Let us see **how groupActions file looks like**. BTW, in the reducer where you receive the groups fetched from the API, make a deep copy of the array: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nodesArray))` for example.

Comment: Hi Facundo! I will update my question and add groupAction.js at the end. But its seems no matters in it. And - yes - I was already trying to parse back stringified array - same result. The issue i see in the json converting or somewhere  near it. Im not sure, but i guess that i will be able to represent the issue without using react or redux

Comment: What do you get when extracting the result here `return json.groups;`?

Comment: I'm getting [Object, Object] as expected. Thanks to your comment i was searching futher, and now i see that something happening when i pass back [...state, action.payload] in the reducer and state not looks like expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just for futher searching. If I was stuck with simple fetching from api, maybe it will save  somebody's time. The thing was as i discover in the pushing back new state with payload. When i console.log whole reducer return, i was able to see inner redux wrapping:
`[].concat(_toConsumableArray(state), [action.payload])`
I was searching redux docs, but not found an explanations of internal design. But its point me to find solution of my issue.

Finally, I modified the reducer like:

```
const initialState = [];
export default function groups(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GROUP_LIST_SUCCESS':
    // make new object from state and payload. No mutations here
    let newStateObject = Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
    // convert the shape of new state to array, so i can iterate it later with map function
    let newStateArray = Array.from(Object.keys(newStateObject), k => newStateObject[k]);
      return newStateArray;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```